# Flags enum in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, enums, enum-flags

I am trying to use a set of conditional statements that will set up an enumeration attributed with [Flags]. However, the compiler complains that 'm' is unassigned. How can I rewrite the following to achieve my intended functionality?

```
Media m;
if (filterOptions.ShowAudioFiles)
    m = m | Media.Audio;
if (filterOptions.ShowDocumentFiles)
    m = m | Media.Document;
if (filterOptions.ShowImageFiles)
    m = m | Media.Image;
if (filterOptions.ShowVideoFiles)
    m = m | Media.Video;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to initialize m.  Create a "None" flag that has value 0 then:

```
Media m = Media.None;
```

Then the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write:

```
Media m = default(Media)
```

Useful in cases where you don't know the enum, class, or whether it's a value/reference type.

Comment: This is really a bad idea, it hides the whole simplicity of enumerations. They were created to remove magic numbers and you are adding it back in when there should be a None for a flags enum that you should use instead.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about the case where you aren't the author, but then explicit choice of the default would be better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the conditions are true m will be undefined. Set it to an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a 'default' like filterOptions.ShowNone? If so, start off with m set to that. The compiler is complaining becuase at the end of all the if's, m might not be set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, besides the fact that this code seems pretty redundant, I'd like to suggest that you use a Select Case instead of all those ugly If's.

Comment: Considering that any combination of the flags could be set, I don't see how a Select Case would be appropriate.

Comment: Agreed, -1 because you could not replace those ifs with a switch.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with the accepted approach is, that you need to have a default element.
In case you do not want to have the `None` element, then you can use nullability.

```cs
Media? m = null;
if (filterOptions.ShowAudioFiles)
    m ??= Media.Audio;
    m = m | Media.Audio;
if (filterOptions.ShowDocumentFiles)
    m ??= Media.Document;
    m = m | Media.Document;
if (filterOptions.ShowImageFiles)
    m ??= Media.Image;
    m = m | Media.Image;
if (filterOptions.ShowVideoFiles)
    m ??= Media.Video;
    m = m | Media.Video;

// in case you require a value for m you can do:
if( m is null ) { throw ... }
```

Answer (score -5):

You don't really need to create a `Media.None`.  You can cast any value to the Flag enum even if it doesn't equal to a value of the flags.

```
Media m = (Media)0;

if (filterOptions.ShowAudioFiles)     m |= Media.Audio; 

if (filterOptions.ShowDocumentFiles)  m |= Media.Document; 

if (filterOptions.ShowImageFiles)     m |= Media.Image; 

if (filterOptions.ShowVideoFiles)     m |= Media.Video;
```

Comment: What if all the conditions fail? What if 0 is e.g. Media.Audio? You need a *valid* initial value.

Comment: This is bad advice. You are always better off using explicit values than relying on integer casts.

Comment: Not really.  The enum will still work perfectly fine even if there isn't a "valid" flag set.  There will still be a value.  All enums are inherited from "Int32" by default.  Yes there could be other problems later if you don't handle default values.  But that is what exceptions are for.

Comment: Since it's a flags enum, the None value ought to map to 0 (no bits set).  Doing it any other way would just be weird.  On the other hand you may want a Media.Default which does have some bits set.

Comment: Ouch. So you wait until later when an exception is raised rather than initializing your data properly in the forst place? Ouch again.

Comment: Keep in mind the Media.None can be confusing as well becasue you can't do a mask check for the values.  If you have standard logic to check for an enum value such as if (input & selectedmask == selectedMask) will always true if selectedMask = Media.None

Comment: @Matthew: If someone were to use Media.None in that fashion, it's their own damn fault for not understanding enums.

Comment: I'm enjoying that this is still collecting down votes even though `Media m = 0;` alone is valid c#.